# Aggregate array of objects based on to attributes in Typescript

Tags: typescript, aggregate, reduce

I have e.g. this array in typescript:

```
const array = [
  { id_m: "123",
    period: "Q1/22",
    amount: 1000
  },
  { id_m: "123",
    period: "Q1/22",
    amount: 500
  },
  { id_m: "123",
    period: "Q2/22",
    amount: 100
  },
]
```

I want to reduce this array based on the properties id_m and period by summing up the amount. The output should be:

```
const output = [
  { id_m: "123",
    period: "Q1/22",
    amount: 1500
  },
  { id_m: "123",
    period: "Q2/22",
    amount: 100
  }
]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First type your data, then you can use `reduce` array method, adding to the accumulated values the type you created, something like:

```js
type Data = {
  id_m: string;
  period: string;
  amount: number;
}

const array: Data[] = [
  { id_m: "123",
    period: "Q1/22",
    amount: 1000
  },
  { id_m: "123",
    period: "Q1/22",
    amount: 500
  },
  { id_m: "123",
    period: "Q2/22",
    amount: 100
  }
];

const result = array.reduce((acc: Data[], info: Data) => {
  const hasItem = acc.find((a) => a.id_m === info.id_m && a.period === info.period);
  if (hasItem) {
    const idx = acc.findIndex((a) => a.id_m === info.id_m && a.period === info.period);
    acc[idx].amount += info.amount;
  } else {
    acc.push(info);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```